# MSTest where constructor leads to asynchronous method

Tags: wpf

I have a viewmodel whose constructor leads to some asynchronous calls and I'm having trouble testing their result.

```cs
public ExamAcquireImageViewModel(ICore coreInstance, ExamManager examManager, Action cancelHandler) : base(examManager)
{
    TemplateVm.OnSelectionChanged += StartAcquiringImages;
    
    // BECAUSE OF PREVIOUS LINE, THIS CALLS StartAcquiringImages()
    SelectedLocationInTemplate = SelectedLocationInTemplate ?? FindNextLowest();
}

private void StartAcquiringImages(LocationViewModel nextLocation = null)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        // expensive operation
        _recon = _coreInstance.AcquireImageSet(Exam, SelectedLocationInTemplate.LocationModel);

        int width = 1000; 
        int height = 1000;

        // (less) expensive operation
        AcquiredImage = _recon?.RenderImageAndGetCurrentFrame().ToWriteableBitmap(width, height);

       SelectedLocationInTemplate = GetNextLocation();
    }).Start();
}
```

The constructor assigns the `OnSelectionChanged` and then changes the selection, setting off the image acquisition process. I want to test that `AcquireImages` has been assigned to.

```
public void TestAcquisition()
{ 
    ExamAcquireImageViewModel acqVm = new ExamAcquireImageViewModel(mockCore.Object, examManager, () => { });

    Assert.IsNotNull(acqVm.AcquiredImage); 
}
```

I have all my Moqs set up correctly. However because of the threaded/asynchronous operations, the test fails because the assertion runs before any `AcquiredImage` gets set (indeed, I imagine, before anything in the `new Thread` gets run).

I've tried `ExamAcquireImageViewModel acqVm = await new ExamAcquireImageViewModel(mockCore.Object, examManager, () => { });` but that doesn't compile (no `GetAwaiter` etc).

**How do I wait for this thread in my tests?**

I'll also want to test that the `SelectedLocationInTemplate` "increments" automatically and each next image gets acquired (see last line in the `Thread`). I don't know where I'd intercept or "peek into" the whole process to see that happening.

Comment: *How do I wait for this thread in my tests?* You can't because the way of how your code is written. It's not testable. You should mock the `Thread` with something that can be controlled in a unit test, like for example a `Task` with a custom scheduler or an interface.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has a similar problem, I will answer my own question.

It's very very very simple. `Thread.Sleep`.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestAcquisitionSucess()
{
    ExamAcquireImageViewModel acqVm = GetAcqVm();
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    Assert.IsNotNull(acqVm.AcquiredImage);
}
```